# How to load csv file into python GUI to create a map without using pandas/numby or matplotlib

Tags: python, csv

I have created a frame in Python GUI.I have a large csv data with this format:
"n",-x,y     where n is an integer counting from 1 onward,x is a coordinate with negative number and y having a positive number.I want to use create_polygon method in canvas to create a map by using  this csv data file .Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

python has a CSV module that makes it easy to parse csvs. I recommend using the namedtuple class factory in the collections module to make working with your csvs easier.

EX:

```
def read_csv(filepath):
    Row = collections.namedtuple('Row', ['n', 'x', 'y'])
    with open(filepath) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            yield Row(*row)


with open('testfile.csv', 'w') as file:
    print('"1", -5, -8', file = file)
    print('"2", -8, -20', file=file)
for row in read_csv('testfile.csv'):
    print(f'{row.n} = {row.x}, {row.y}')`
```

OUTPUT:

`1 =  -5,  -8`

`2 =  -8,  -20`